# Changing the order of `getGroupChildNames`

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I've added a new tab to the `product.info.details` block, and would like it to be shown first (before the "Review" and "More Information" tabs).

I can't seem to change the order with the `before` and `after` attributes, or the `move` instruction, since `getGroupChildNames` doesn't seem to take the order into account.

The two options that I see are:

- create a plugin and somehow force a reorder (maybe using `Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure::reorderChildElement`
- Overwrite the template (`product/view/details.phtml`), preg_match the block name and hardcode it to go first.

Any other options? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while creating a custom theme.

The solution I used (not sure if it is the best one) was to get Child Names (`$block->getChildNames()`), which will return an array of the sorted list of the childs, and to filter it with the group names.

You will end ud with the sorted array of the child names belonging to the `detailed_info` group.

Here is some code to clarify it :

File `product/view/details.phtml` :

```
<?php /* ... Code ... */ ?>
<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <?php $childNames = $block->getChildNames();?>
    <?php $detailedInfoGroup = array_intersect($childNames, $detailedInfoGroup); ?>
<?php /* ... Code ... */ ?>
```

Comment: Nice trick, works great and was just what I needed, thanks